# How to authenticate serverless web request using AWS Web API and Lambda?

Tags: python, authentication, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Little background info,

I have built an interactive website where users can upload images to S3.  I built it so the image upload goes right from the browser to AWS S3 using a signed request ( python django backend ).

Now the issue is, the users wish to be able to rotate the image.  I Similarly I would like this set up so the user's request goes straight from the browser.  I built an AWS Lambda function and attached it to a web api, which will accept POST requests.  I have been testing and I finally got it working.  The function takes 2 inputs, `key`, and `rotate_direction`, which are passed as POST variables to the web api.  They come into the python function in the `event` variable.  Here is the simple Lambda function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
from PIL import Image

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def rotate_image(image_path, upload_path, rotate_direction):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        if rotate_direction == "right":
            image.rotate(-90).save(upload_path)
        else:
            image.rotate(90).save(upload_path)

def handler(event, context):
    bucket = 'the-s3-bucket-name'
    key = event['key']
    rotate_direction = event['rotate_direction']
    download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
    upload_path = '/tmp/rotated_small-{}'.format(key)


    s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
    rotate_image(download_path, upload_path, rotate_direction)
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, bucket, key)

    return { 'message':'rotated' }
```

Everything is working.  So now my issue is how to enforce some kind of authentication for this system?  The ownership details about each image reside on the django web server.  While all the images are considered "public", I wish to enforce that only the owner of each image is allowed to rotate their own images.

With this project I have been venturing into new territory by making content requests right from the browser.  I could understand how I could control access by only making the POST requests from the web server, where I could validate the ownership of the images.  Would it still be possible having the request come from the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR Solution: create a Cognito Identity Pool, assign policy users can only upload files prefixed by their Identity ID.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to setup a way for an image stored on S3 to be **viewable by public**, yet only **editable by the user who uploaded it**. Actually, you can verify file ownership, rotate the image and upload the rotated image to S3 all in the browser without going through a Lambda function.

Step 1: Create a Cognito User Pool to create a user directory. If you already have a user login/sign up authentication system, you could skip this step.

Step 2: Create a Cognito Identify Pool to enable federated identity, so your users can get a temporary AWS credential from the Identity Pool, and use it to upload files to S3 without going through your server/lambda.

Step 3: When creating the Cognito Identity Pool, you can define a policy on what S3 resources a user is allowed to access. Here is a sample policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:*",
        "cognito-identity:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_S3_UPLOADS_BUCKET_NAME/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_S3_UPLOADS_BUCKET_NAME/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note the second block assigns "S3:GetObject" to all files in your S3 bucket; and the third block assigns "S3:PutObject" to ONLY FILES prefixed with the user's Cognito Identity ID.

Step 4: In frontend JS, get a temporary credential from Cognito Identity Pool

```
export function getAwsCredentials(userToken) {
  const authenticator = `cognito-idp.${config.cognito.REGION}.amazonaws.com/${config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID}`;

  AWS.config.update({ region: config.cognito.REGION });

  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    Logins: {
      [authenticator]: userToken
    }
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
    AWS.config.credentials.get((err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }

      resolve();
    })
  ));
}
```

Step 5: Upload files to S3 with the credential, prefix the file name with the user's Cognito Identity ID.

```
export async function s3Upload(file, userToken) {
  await getAwsCredentials(userToken);

  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
      Bucket: config.s3.BUCKET,
    }
  });
  const filename = `${AWS.config.credentials.identityId}-${Date.now()}-${file.name}`;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
    s3.putObject({
      Key: filename,
      Body: file,
      ContentType: file.type,
      ACL: 'public-read',
    },
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }

      resolve(`${config.s3.DOMAIN}/${config.s3.BUCKET}/${filename}`);
    })
  ));
}
```

Comment: This is quite a strong answer.  Thanks so much.  Will def read through the tutorial and see how to integrate this.  My app actually uses Firebase for user authentication, but file upload uses a "presigned request" (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls) from my server, and passes this back to the client before the client can upload the image.  It seems with your technique here I would be able to skip that step (less server).  Also right now all the images do not have any special prefix, so i'll have to re-work all that a bit.

Comment: Glad you found a way around. Yeah, according to Amazon's doc, you either prefix the filename or store the images in user ID prefixed folder names.

Comment: Yeah now that you say this I realize that is how they have handled the file naming on other projects I have worked on.  I figured I didn't need it because the database the DB contains ownership info, but now I can see how naming with a special code for each user can help.